# How to insert Google Search google autocomplete to TextBox1.TextChanged in C#?

Tags: c#, autocomplete

When I type on Google Web Search, it send a URL to server:

```
string q = "keywords";
string url = "https://www.google.com.vn/s?hl=vi&gs_nf=1&tok=QsGiZnZo-E6Tp4AB-_2zlg&cp=2&gs_id=d&xhr=t&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=bb84745dfff12f1f&biw=1366&bih=667&tch=1&ech=2&psi=4OQhUJXMNYejiQfToIHYAQ.1344398521888.1&q=";
url += System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(q) //This is URl
```

if I paste this URL to address bar, the browser force me download a "s" file.
Is any way to insert this autocomplete to TextBox1.TextChanged?

in the "s" file contain the suggest of the word I type in Google's TextBox. Example, if I type "stack", chorme sent above URL to server, and return a "s" file, inside have word like: "stackoverflow", "stack c++", "stack docklet". My mind is when I'm typing in Form1.TextBox1, it auto send the TextBox1.Text to Google server, and process the return "s" file, like the way Google suggest keyword.

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense, Tuyen. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: your question doesn't make any sense. And by copying pasting your original post.... still doesnt make sense.